# Can you pass an argument to a windows ON_BN_CLICKED macro?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, mfc

I have a Windows GUI program (Visual Studio 2019) with many buttons that perform the same operation but on a different device. Rather than have 20 different macro calls along the lines of:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CChainDlg, CDialogEx)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_CHECK_1, &CChainDlg::OnBnClickedCheck1)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_CHECK_2, &CChainDlg::OnBnClickedCheck2)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_CHECK_3, &CChainDlg::OnBnClickedCheck3)
    ...
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
...
void CChainDlg::OnBnClickedCheck1() {...}
void CChainDlg::OnBnClickedCheck2() {...}
void CChainDlg::OnBnClickedCheck3() {...}
```

... each of which performs the same basic algorithm, only differing in an array index, I'd like to have one call that can accept an index.

The ON_BN_CLICKED macro does not want to take arguments which would seem like the most obvious way of accomplishing this.  E.g.:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CChainDlg, CDialogEx)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_CHECK_1, &CChainDlg::OnBnClickedCheck(0))
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_CHECK_2, &CChainDlg::OnBnClickedCheck(1))
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_CHECK_3, &CChainDlg::OnBnClickedCheck(2))
    ...
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

What I currently do is write the generic function that takes an argument and have the individual OnBnClickedCheck1() functions call the generic function with the correct argument. But that just seems messy.

Suggest to me a better way!

Comment: If the argument is known at runtime you can templatize the function. - `ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_CHECK_3, &CChainDlg::OnBnClickedCheck<3>)`

Comment: It seems that template is the best way, if you don't know about it, I suggest you read this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/templates-cpp?view=msvc-170).

Comment: @CaptainObvlious That should probably read *"If the argument is known at **compile time**"*. Also *"templatizing"* is a misnomer. A more accurate description would be to instantiate a function template.

Comment: @IInspectable Uh Yep as a matter of fact it should.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your button control IDs are sequential in value, you can use the [`ON_CONTROL_RANGE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/message-map-macros-mfc?view=msvc-170#on_control_range) macro to map all of the controls to a single handler, eg:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CChainDlg, CDialogEx)
    ON_CONTROL_RANGE( BN_CLICKED, IDC_CHECK_1, IDC_CHECK_3, &CChainDlg::OnBnClicked ) 
    ...
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
...
void CChainDlg::OnBnClicked(UINT nID) {...}
```

Now your handler can take a parameter that tells it which control triggered the notification.

This is described in more detail on MSDN:

[Handlers for Message-Map Ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/handlers-for-message-map-ranges?view=msvc-170)

Comment: I think this is the better answer between this and @xMri answers.  But I appreciate xMri's answer nonetheless.  While their answer was really more along the lines of what I was thinking, I like the cleanliness of ON_CONTROL_RANGE over ON_COMMAND_EX.  I didn't know about either of these, and now I've seen them I'm embarrassed I didn't find it in the help files.  OTOH, getting help on ON_BN_CLICKED does not seem to lead to anything else helpful.
Remy Lebeau and xMRi:  you're awesome!  Learned something new today!

Comment: The main difference between using `ON_CONTROL_RANGE()` and `ON_COMMAND_EX/_RANGE()` is that the former will be triggered only on the specific notification you want, whereas the latter will be triggered on *every* `WM_COMMAND` message regardless of its notification code. `BN_CLICKED` is not the only button notification to be carried by `WM_COMMAND`

Answer (score 1):

To expand on [Captain Obvlious](https://stackoverflow.com/users/845568/captain-obvlious)'s comment: You could use a template method:

```cpp
class CChainDlg {
  BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CChainDlg, CDialogEx)
    ON_BN_CLICKED   ( IDC_CHECK_1,  &CChainDlg::OnBnClickedCheck<1> )
    ON_BN_CLICKED   ( IDC_CHECK_2,  &CChainDlg::OnBnClickedCheck<2> )
    ON_BN_CLICKED   ( IDC_CHECK_3,  &CChainDlg::OnBnClickedCheck<3> )
    ...
  END_MESSAGE_MAP()

  template<size_t idx>
  void OnBnClickedCheck() {
    ... my_array[idx] ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Yep that's what I'm talkin about. +1 cuz I was busy stuffin' my face with some delicious cake ;)

Comment: Note that this approach still creates multiple functions in the program's memory, it just simplifies the duplicated code. It is also not the best approach anyway. Microsoft offers a [native solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/handlers-for-message-map-ranges?view=msvc-170) that better matches what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ON_COMMAND_EX`. Because you just have a BN_CLICKED event here this will work:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CChainDlg, CDialogEx)
    ON_COMMAND_EX( IDC_CHECK_1, &CChainDlg::OnBnClicked ) 
    ON_COMMAND_EX( IDC_CHECK_2, &CChainDlg::OnBnClicked ) 
    ...
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
...
BOOL CChainDlg::OnBnClicked(UINT nID) {...}
```

Comment: This looks like a great option!  Please see my comment to Remy's post.  Thank you for taking the time to provide an answer!

Comment: Note that there is also `ON_COMMAND_EX_RANGE()` (undocumented), eg: `ON_COMMAND_EX_RANGE( IDC_CHECK_1, IDC_CHECK_3, &CChainDlg::OnBnClicked )`

Comment: @RemyLebeau, how did you find that?

Comment: Reading the source code and the headers of the MFC...

Comment: I just wanted to share this `COMMAND_EX` too. It is documented in MSDN  [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/tn006-message-maps?view=msvc-170). It is not available in ClassWizard, but you can insert it manually`.

Comment: @ElRonaldo I found it by looking in `afxmsg_.h` directly.